Load and process csv file in javascript within Qualtrics
I am trying to load a csv file within Qualtrics's javascript code and filter it based on the values within it. My csv file was created with the following r script:
d <- structure(list(U = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 
                    T = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                    aE = c("X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), 
                    aA = c("R", "S", "S", "T", "U", "V"), 
                    aX = c("P", "Q", "Q", "W", "P", "P"), 
                    aP = c("Z", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "A"), 
                    aJ = c("K", "L", "L", "K", "K", "L"), 
                    aD = c("C", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D"), 
                    bE = c("X", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "Y"), 
                    bA = c("G", "R", "R", "I", "I", "T"), 
                    bX = c("M", "N", "N", "O", "M", "O"), 
                    bP = c("Z", "A", "A", "Z", "A", "Z"), 
                    bJ = c("K", "L", "L", "L", "K", "L"), 
                    bD = c("B", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C")), 
               row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
               class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

write.csv(d, "data.csv")

The csv file looks like the following:

EDIT
The csv file in a text editor is the following:
"","U","T","aE","aA","aX","aP","aJ","aD","bE","bA","bX","bP","bJ","bD"
"1","a",1,"X","R","P","Z","K","C","X","G","M","Z","K","B"
"2","b",2,"Y","S","Q","A","L","B","Y","R","N","A","L","C"
"3","c",3,"Y","S","Q","A","L","B","Y","R","N","A","L","C"
"4","d",4,"Y","T","W","A","K","B","X","I","O","Z","L","C"
"5","e",5,"Y","U","P","Z","K","D","X","I","M","A","K","B"
"6","f",6,"Y","V","P","A","L","D","Y","T","O","Z","L","C"


I then load it in javascript and attempt to process it using the following code:
$(document).ready(function() {
    var task = '1';
    var userID = 'a';

    fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo/main/data.csv')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(csvData => {
            // Parse CSV data into an array of rows
            var rows = csvData.trim().split('\n');

            // Extract headers and trim whitespace
            var headers = rows[0].split(',').map(header => header.trim());

            // Extract and parse each row (excluding headers)
            var data = rows.slice(1).map(row => {
                var rowValues = row.split(',').map(value => value.trim());
                var rowData = {};

                headers.forEach((header, index) => {
                    rowData[header] = rowValues[index];
                });

                return rowData;
            });

            console.log('Parsed Data:', data);

            // Filter data to only include rows that match the specified task and userID
            var filteredData = data.filter(row => row['T'] === task && row['U'] === userID);

            console.log('Filtered Data:', filteredData);

            // Display the filtered row in the HTML document
            if (filteredData.length > 0) {
                var resultRow = filteredData[0]; // Get the first (and only) matching row
                displayResultRow(resultRow); // Call function to display the row in the document
            } else {
                console.log('No matching row found.');
                // Handle case where no matching row is found
            }

            return filteredData; // Return the filtered array of data objects
        })
        .then(filteredData => {
            console.log('Returned Filtered Data:', filteredData);
            // Use the returned filtered array of data objects here or perform additional actions
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching or processing CSV:', error);
            // Handle fetch or processing errors
        });

    function displayResultRow(row) {
        // Assuming there is a container in your HTML document with id="resultContainer"
        var resultContainer = document.getElementById('resultContainer');
        
        // Clear previous content
        resultContainer.innerHTML = '';

        // Create and append elements to display the row data
        Object.keys(row).forEach(key => {
            var rowElement = document.createElement('div');
            rowElement.textContent = `${key}: ${row[key]}`;
            resultContainer.appendChild(rowElement);
        });
    }
});


The initial data loading works, as I am able to successfully see the data object. However none of the processing works successfully. I believe this is because the columns and rows may not be created correctly. This is how the data object looks in my js code editor:
Parsed Data:
(6) [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, ...]
0
:
(15) {"": ""1"", "U": ""1...}
1
:
(15) {"": ""2"", "U": ""2...}
2
:
(15) {"": ""3"", "U": ""3...}
3
:
(15) {"": ""4"", "U": ""4...}
4
:
(15) {"": ""5"", "U": ""5...}
5
:
(15) {"": ""6"", "U": ""6...}

This seems to me like the row numbers are being read in, and the column headers are treated as other values of some sort. In any case, the data filtering is not working. I also am unsure how to store the data object to access it.
How can I take the csv file that I successfully load into javascript, process it to select the only row that has U = the specified userID above, and T = the specified task above? How can I store this row as an object (say, entitled info_object) so that I can then extract the specific values of particular columns within that row (ex: save the value of aE as the object "info_aE")?

Instead of showing how the csv was generated, it would be better to show the contents of the generated csv file.  That would allow people to give better answers.

Absolutely, thank you. I have added an image showing the contents of the csv file.

It would be 100x more helpful if you opened the CSV file in a text editor, copied it and pasted it into your question.
An image screenshot of the CSV doesn't really tell us whether the CSV is using quotes or not.

Apologies for my misunderstanding, I've now added the version from text edit.

You are not stripping the quotes from the values. With the CSV format, quotes may appear, especially if the data value contains a ,

Thanks, so how can I modify the above code to deal with this?

Here is a working snippet demonstrating the use of yet another CSV parser library:


const text=`"","U","T","aE","aA","aX","aP","aJ","aD","bE","bA","bX","bP","bJ","bD"
"1","a",1,"X","R","P","Z","K","C","X","G","M","Z","K","B"
"2","b",2,"Y","S","Q","A","L","B","Y","R","N","A","L","C"
"3","c",3,"Y","S","Q","A","L","B","Y","R","N","A","L","C"
"4","d",4,"Y","T","W","A","K","B","X","I","O","Z","L","C"
"5","e",5,"Y","U","P","Z","K","D","X","I","M","A","K","B"
"6","f",6,"Y","V","P","A","L","D","Y","T","O","Z","L","C"`;

// in the actual situation you would retrieve the text 
// from your file, using asynchronous fetch(URL).then(r=>r.text())
// In a further .then(text=>{...}) you would place the following:
const res=Papa.parse(text,{header:true,dynamicTyping:true}).data;
 console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.4.1/papaparse.min.js"></script>



Alternatively you could retrieve the text directly from your URL with
Papa.parse(URL,{download:true,header:true,dynamicTyping:true,complete:({data:res})=>{
 console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
}
});


Unreal, that works! Thank you so very much! As someone with very little JS experience, this was super helpful. Much appreciated!

You really don't need to write your own CSV parser. Take a look at this fast and easy to use library csv-parse:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse
While it is available and often used with NodeJS backends, it comes with an ESM distribution suitable for use in browser, as explained here:
https://csv.js.org/parse/distributions/browser_esm/

Thank you for the recommendation. I'm afraid I don't quite understand how to use this based on the documentation. I'm using this javascript in Qualtrics's JS code, to run a survey. Would I be able to run this parser within Qualtrics's code? If so, how? Is it the same as using it in browser, and if so can you provide an example of how to make it run in browser as the suggested documentation doesn't seem to work for me? (I can't import it, etc.)

@flâneur Sorry, I'm not familiar with Qualtrics. This page does seem to indicate you can load external JS libs (though you'd have to host it somewhere I suppose, which isn't too hard): https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/question-options/add-javascript/
You might want to tag this post so it shows up for Qualtrics people too.
